# yadcf range_number in single input field

Tags: yadcf

I am using yadcf 0.9.2 version for my datatable. For range_number columns, i'm trying to achieve filtering rows in one input field for mainly two features(multi_Select,range_number).
The multi_select will work but range_number has two fields which I would like to limit to one input field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTjsl.png)

Is it possible to specify the range format in one input field as shown in image?
This way i can use single input for multi-values selection and also range can be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the 'from' range input using css and that way you will have to 'to' filter only.

```
#id-of-from-range-input {
    display: none;
}
.yadcf-filter-wrapper-inner {
    border: none;
}
```